# jquery library conflicts with custom code

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am using this code to include CSS and JS files on my site:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/sticky_notes/sticky_notes.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/sticky_notes/styles.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="/includes/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.2.6.css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/css/navigation.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/css/tabs.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/includes/css/popup_calendar.css" type="text/css" media="all">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

i use autocomplete from jquery on a form which works fine if `sticky_notes.js` is not included, but i also need this code to be executed. how can i get it all working? i have tried using multiple versions of jquery

Comment: What's the conflict?

Comment: Could you provide more details please?

Comment: my jquery autocomplete doesnt work unless i remove the sticky_notes.js file

Answer (score 0):

The sticky notes plugin is built on jQuery 1.3.2. You include jQuery 1.10.2. The chances were incredibly high that it won't work because of backwards incompatibly changes between 1.3.2 and 1.10.2.

Solution: Find yourself another plugin for that purpose. You simply can't use something that hasn't changed from Jan 2010 (almost 5 years).

Try this: http://postitall.txusko.com/plugin.html . It's newer. It will most probably work.
Also there's the option to roll your own, it's not that hard.

Comment: im not too sure on that one - this is the code i have currently: http://pastebin.com/r0Npqzzj - could this not just be changed into a newer version of query?

Comment: If you pay someone to do it, I'm sure it can be upgraded. But it looks like the original author of the plugin did not care so much as to do it himself for free.

Comment: whats not available in this code in the latest version of jquery? - http://pastebin.com/r0Npqzzj

Comment: You're not willing to make any effort on this, are you?